# I need help with specific measurement

Tags: measurement

there!

I'm struggling with the measurement right now. I'm new at this and I'm trying to create a business card mockup. I have a specific size, 3.5x2 inches. But I can't get the size right. Can anyone guide me, please?

Comment: hello could you please show a screenshot? Why can't you have it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to scene properties, set Unit System to Imperial and lenght to Inches.

Add a plane, set the desired measures in the dimensions tab, then press Ctrl A to Apply the scale.

[image]